# Using External JS Files With Firebase V9

Tags: javascript, firebase

With Firebase now, all Javascript must be written within the SDK module tags that you import from the Firebase dashboard.

If anything is outside of this module and you go to use things like 'getFirestore' or 'getAuth' it will just say that its 'not defined'

So using an external script file means that.... If you put scripts in that external file that have firebase functions in them they wont work..

How can I go about using the external .js files with Firebase V9?
Does this have something to do with the new WebPack integration? I don't really understand WebPack yet..

Thanks